# ASP.NET Web API for currency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

On the basis of the daily exchange rate data of the CB (https://ww.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js) it is necessary to create a Web-service using ASP.Net Core, which implements 2 API methods:

1. `GET /currencies` - should return the list of currencies with the possibility of pagination
2. `GET /currency/` - must return the exchange rate for the transferred currency identifier

I want to know what mistakes I have. What should I fix and how?

Class (and interface) who parsing website (Register as transient):

```
public interface ICurrentCurrency
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Valute>> GetCurrencies();
}

public class CurrentCurrency : ICurrentCurrency
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Valute>> GetCurrencies()
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

        IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        handler.Proxy = proxy;

        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
        var content = await client.GetAsync("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js");
        string json = await content.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var obj = JObject.Parse(json)["Valute"].ToString();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Valute>>(obj).Select(x => x.Value);
    }
}
```

In `Main` (.NET 6 syntax):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICurrentCurrency, CurrentCurrency>();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseRouting();

app.Run();
```

Model:

```
public class Valute
{
    [JsonProperty("ID")]
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CharCode { get; set; }
    public string NumCode { get; set; }
    public int Nominal { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public decimal Previous { get; set; }
}
```

Class for pagination:

```
public class CurrencyPageParameters
{
    public const int MaxPageSize = 5;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    public int _pageSize;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get => _pageSize;
        set => _pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value;
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[action]")]
public class CbrCurrencyController : ControllerBase
{
    private ICurrentCurrency _currency;
    public CbrCurrencyController(ICurrentCurrency currency)
    {
        _currency = currency;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("currency")]
    public async Task<Valute> GetCurrency(string id)
    {
        var item = (await _currency.GetCurrencies()).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return item;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("currencies")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Valute>> Currencies([FromQuery] CurrencyPageParameters @params)
    {
        var data = (await _currency.GetCurrencies()).Skip((@params.PageNumber - 1) * @params.PageSize).Take(@params.PageSize);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `GetCurrencies`

- I would suggest to create a named/typed `HttpClient` with the proxy handler to make it reusable

  - In [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526095/how-to-configure-web-proxy-for-httpclient-created-directly-via-httpclientfactory) you can read more about the solution

```
serviceCollection
    .AddHttpClient("currencyClient")
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() {
        IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Proxy = httpProxy 
    });
```

- I would also recommend to set the base url of the `HttpClient` rather than passing the whole url all the time

```
serviceCollection
    .AddHttpClient("currencyClient"), c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/");
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(...);
```

- After these modifications your method could be simplified like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Valute>> GetCurrencies()
{
    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(currencyClient);
    var content = await client.GetAsync("daily_json.js");
    ...
}
```

- I would also suggest to consider to use the [ReadFromJsonAsync](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-6.0) extension method of the `HttpContent` class to perform the deserialization
- It might make sense to introduce some caching here to reduce the network traffic and the overall response time

#### `CbrCurrencyController`

- You can mark your `_currency` `private` field as `readonly`

#### `GetCurrency`

- Inside the `FirstOrDefault` you might want to perform case insensitive string comparison

```
.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Id, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

- I would also suggest to return with 404 if the provided id does not have a corresponding currency

  - In this case you have to use `ActionResult` class

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Valute>> GetCurrency(string id)
{
    var currencies = await _currency.GetCurrencies();
    Valute item = currencies.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Id, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    return item ?? NotFound();
}
```

#### `Currencies`

- I would suggest to perform some preliminary checks on your input model

  - Like the `PageNumber` and `PageSize` fields are greater than 1
- I would also recommend to check whether you are not over-paging (skipping more items than it is available)

  - Just to make it clear the `Skip` and the `Take` will not break in case of over-paging the result will be an empty collection, but it does not make too much sense to perform such request

Comment: Thanks a lot!! What about return value in `Currencies` method? I returned `Task<IEnumerable<Valute>>`, how can I return `Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Valute>>>`?

Comment: @Aarnihauta On the happy path use `return Ok(...);` on the malformed/invalid parameter path use `return BadRequest(...);`

Answer (score 1):

I would remove filtering/paging (`.FirstOrDefault(), .Skip()` etc...) logic from `CbrCurrencyController`  actions.

This work should be done by service, not inside controller.

Another suggestion, url's, file names and sim should not be hard-coded in code, but configurable using some kind of configuration service...